# Random string in URL helpful against "Man in the Middle Attack"?

Tags: php, security, ssl, man-in-the-middle

Here's the scenario:

On every non-shopping-cart page a new md5(rand()) session variable is generated. This variable is then inserted into the url for shopping cart links. Clicking the cart link would be the point at which a user is transferred from http to https so I understand that this is a crucial transaction to secure in order to prevent a man in the middle from injecting himself between the server and the user.

In order to access the shopping cart the current session variable must match the string in the url (eg "/shopping_car_url/{random_string}/"), otherwise a 404 error is sent.

1. Should this be effective as long as the session is not compromised?
2. Would using a POST variable (or the same or different random strings in both session and post) be as or more effective (or ineffective)?
3. If this is effective, is there any benefit to doing the same thing through the rest of the cart editing / checkout process or would this be pointless since the user is already connected to SSL at this point?

Comment: How do you plan to indentify which value generated with `md5(rand())` is supposed to be accepted / avoided?

Comment: And what is the presence of that slug supposed to prove? A man in the middle would have no problem intercepting the slug when it's sent over HTTP.

Comment: @PHP Newb, the session variable would be overwritten if page was not "shopping cart". On shopping cart page it would test that the url matched it then would be overwritten.

Comment: @duskwuff, I guess the only thing it's doing is forcing the man in the middle to set a session variable to a value he intercepts via http. Can a session variable be set so easily by a malicious user that this is not useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to protect yourself against here is [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) (Cross Site Request Forgery) and not MITM.

Once you switch to https a MITM attack is virtually impossible and adding items to a cart typically doesn't require CSRF protection (unlike the payment action itself). Make sure to also read [XSS & CSRF: Practical explotation of post-authentication vulnerabilities](https://www.htbridge.com/publication/practical_exploitation_of_post_authentication_vulnerabilities_web.pdf).

However, if a malicious person manages to position themselves in between the user and your site before you switch to https, they would be able to rewrite your shop links as well, but without using https; it would then be up to your users to be vigilant about the lock icon in the address bar.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. To eliminate the last scenario I should force SSL connection on cart and checkout via htaccess then. This would force an attacker to redirect the user to another page/domain instead of allowing him to use my checkout page without SSL, yes?

Comment: @LittleGoomba Not really, it forces the attacker to keep serving pages over http rather than https; forcing https on your side won't matter, because the attacker can proxy traffic to your https without a problem; I should tell you that MITM is not a very likely scenario unless the user's system itself is compromised.

Comment: +1, CSRF attacks are a considerable threat these days. Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: "you typically won't need to protect against CSRF" is an untrue statement.  CSRF/XSRF attacks can come from any vector, including unexpected ones.  Having intermediate screens won't necessarily stop attacks.

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother with it. Keep your URLs simple and straightforward; your customers will be much happier. If you're using SSL correctly, you are protected against the vast majority of transport-layer man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: All other urls will be straightforward and I'm not too concerned about people not being able to link directly to the cart (would only be accessible through the link so you can be issued a cookie). I could do it as a post to prevent the messy URL but I'm more worried about whether the concept is sound security-wise. It would force the man in the middle to set a session variable but I'm not sure how difficult that might be.

Comment: As I said before, if you're using SSL securely, you are protected from most man-in-the-middle attacks by the very nature of SSL.